# ERROR No .NET SDKs were found al crear tabla en tutorial de farmacia de genexus

Tags: json, genexus

Al seguir el tutorial farmacia que viene en la página oficial, me aparece un error al crear las tablas, me aparece lo siguiente:

> dotnet publish -nologo -v q  /p:PdfLibrary=ITEXT "C:\Users\TAPIA\OneDrive\Documentos\GENEXUS\PROYECTO\FARMACIA\FARMACIA1\CloudNET002\web\GxDeps.csproj" -o "C:\Users\TAPIA\OneDrive\Documentos\GENEXUS\PROYECTO\FARMACIA\FARMACIA1\CloudNET002\web\bin"

> the command could not be loaded, possibly because:
>
> - You intended to execute a .NET application:
>   The application 'publish' does not exist.
> - You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
>   A compatible .NET SDK was not found.
>   Requested SDK version: 6.0.0
>   global.json file: C:\Users\TAPIA\OneDrive\Documentos\GENEXUS\PROYECTO\FARMACIA\FARMACIA1\CloudNET002\global.json
>   Installed SDKs:
>   No .NET SDKs were found.
>   Install the [6.0.0] .NET SDK or update [C:\Users\TAPIA\OneDrive\Documentos\GENEXUS\PROYECTO\FARMACIA\FARMACIA1\CloudNET002\global.json] to match an installed SDK.
>   Download a .NET SDK:

Comment: te fijaste en el wiki de tener los requerimientos bien instalados?